# How to open number dialer pad programmatically in android?

Tags: android, buttonclick, phone-call, numeric-keypad

I want to display Number Dial Keypad (Phone Call) Programmatically on button click in android. Code is available for direct number dialing but I only need to show the dial keypad when I click the Button.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use this code if you want to open the dialer programmatically without any number inserted:

**Java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
startActivity(intent)
```

If you need to open the dialer with the number already digited you can use this code:

**Java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123 456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:123 456789")
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 47):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9999999999"));
startActivity(intent);
```

For this we don't need to add any permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: For ACTION_DIAL, we don't need CALL_PHONE Permission. It needed only for ACTION_CALL

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
startActivity(intent);
```

it will show Dial Window check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL_BUTTON) for information

Answer (score 3):

Make button or any widget example : button1

```
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+button1.getText().toString().trim()));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
    });
```

Add permission in manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void openDialPad(String phoneNumber) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Also, you should register the custom dialscreen as follows in the manifest:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".MyDialerApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in non activity class then create a function like this :

```
package bp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

import session.MyApplication;

/**
 * Created by Atiar Talukdar on 7/11/2019.
 */
public class Utils {

    public static void openDialPad(Activity activity, String phoneNumber) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and then call from anywhare in like :

`Utils.openDialPad(getActivity(),data.getContactNo());`

or

`Utils.openDialPad(this,data.getContactNo());`

Answer (score 0):

This is different, but if you want to access your dialer pad by clicking a number, in your xml, declare the autolink attribute

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code for opening dialer with given mobile number :

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:$text"))
startActivity(intent)
```