# Make call through mobile app

Tags: java, android

### make call

I'm trying to make a call through my app. But my app dials number from android mobile dial pad. I want my dial pad in my call. My code is

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("tel:"); Intent intent=new Intent();intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mobile));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this code helps you.

Comment: Thanks alot.. its working

Comment: @MuhammadMudassar welcom

Comment: Is dafault dial pad is available in app? If yes, please send me code. My lot of time will be save. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In manifest add this permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Then in Activity use this :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + PhoneNO));
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activityx.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. its working...

Comment: Is dafault dial pad is available in app? If yes, please send me code. My lot of time will be save. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309226/how-to-open-number-dialer-pad-programmatically-in-android